# How to insert the combo box inside DFatagrid in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have to insert the combobox inside the DG in silverlight 4. And also it should be binded and the values inside

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an "automatic" way to do this, unless you use some sort of custom third party grid. Otherwise, you'll need to define a custom column with the ComboBox as the template, and then on RowDataBind you can bind the data to the ComboBox ItemsSource property.

I found a post about this that has some examples.

[Forum Post](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/53435.aspx)